# Fixing TWIG Deprecation warning for InitRuntimeInterface

Tags: php, symfony, twig, deprecation-warning

I am getting the following TWIG deprecation warning:

> The "Symfony\Bridge\Twig\Extension\FormExtension" class implements
>   "Twig\Extension\InitRuntimeInterface" that is deprecated since Twig
>   2.7, to be removed in 3.0

However, I cannot find anything regarding what to change. Can someone point me in the right direction on how to resolve this warning?

Comment: What Symfony version are you using? 4.x, earlier?

Comment: Symfony 3.3.18.

Comment: Then that is your issue: https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/18427

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same error and updating twig from `v2.7.2` to `v2.7.4` fixed it.

`composer update twig/twig`

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use `needs_environment` flag instead of using `Twig\Extension\InitRuntimeInterface`.

[You will see how to fix it on this post](https://www.lrotherfield.com/blog/symfony2-get-twig-environment-twig-extension)